# Why can I not post my one post per day on UX?

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, spam, help-center

**I've been trying for 3 days to post one question on [User Experience](https://ux.stackexchange.com/).**

Every time I try, I get the following message:

> You can only post 1 time each day due to the volume of spam and abuse
>   originating from your network. We apologize for any inconvenience. See
>   the help center for more.

[image: Visual Aid of Problem]

I researched more on the issue in the [Help Center](https://ux.stackexchange.com/help/abuse-block) and found the following:

> It means that a number of accounts originating from your area have
>   been detected as being created purely to post unsolicited
>   advertisements, abuse or hate speech, or a combination of the two.
>   Until the system learns to trust your account a little more while you
>   browse from your current location, or the abuse stops (whichever comes
>   first), you may only post on the site two times per 24 hour period.
>
> This block will naturally lift within a day or two, or as soon as
>   established members of the community have expressed approval of some
>   of your contributions. You can try contributing from another location;
>   however, this type of block is generally very temporary.

My account is new, so I realize the block won't be lifted for a long period of time. However, why can't I still post my 1 post every 24 hrs?

**Is this a bug with User Experience or an issue on my end?**

### EDIT - I can post my question

Before I could post my question, they checked if I was a human:

[image: EDIT Visual Aid]

**Did a moderator allow my question to be posted or is this just convenient timing?**

Comment: IIRC, it's an _IP_ based block, not a purely account based one. Hence the line _"You can try contributing from another location"_ in the Help Center. If it's limited to 1 question per day from your _network_ that would explain it- Someone else is getting that question in each day before you can. (I could be a bit off on this, which is why I am not posting an answer.)

Comment: Indeed. Or you tried to post a question using a secondary account.

Comment: I used to use a different account, but that account is now deleted. I'm the only person who uses Stack Exchange in my IP Address. Can a moderator personally remove the one post per day issue? Please note, I'm no longer posting with my other account.

Comment: _"I'm the only person who uses Stack Exchange in my IP Address"_ Are you sure about that? Are you on a home network where you can account for all the other users, or are you on a public, work, or school network? If the latter, then I doubt you can really guarantee that...

Comment: I'm on a home network. I'm the only one interested in Stack Exchange. I believe the issue is coming from my old account or from a issue with the UX website. Can a moderator fix the issue manually?

Comment: A moderator must have manually allowed my network to post questions on UX. Otherwise, timing has never been more convenient...

Comment: There are definitely more than two accounts using this IP address on Stack Overflow. I don't have access to IP info on UX, but I would bet it's the same deal. One of the other accounts had posted within the last 24 hours.

Comment: How certain are you that you're not on Carrier-Grade NAT, which shares your IP with numerous other ISP customers?

Comment: @mmyers Your correct in this statement. Is Stack Exchange considered one network or is each individual site considered a network? I never posted on Meta...

Comment: @NathanTuggy I use a home network and Century Link.

Comment: I am a moderator on UX.Stackexchange. You are not the only account from that IP address. As @mmyers states; there are more than two other active accounts on that IP.

Comment: @JonW These must be old accounts I don't use. Is there a way for moderators to delete all accounts associated with an IP Address but this one?

Comment: All the accounts are active on the site. Basically - you have a IP address that other active accounts also have. Make of that as you will.

Comment: I am **positive** that all of these accounts are mine. No one else in my IP address uses Stack Exchange. Can I give you permission to delete the other accounts in my IP Address, regardless if they're active or not? These other accounts are ruining my experience on the Stack Exchange sites...

Comment: @CodePlay If it's actually what Nathan Tuggy suggests, as in you sharing your external IP with multiple other customers, then you really don't have the authority to have those accounts deleted. You'd have to prove that you own the accounts first.

Comment: @JonW You mention how I have other active accounts on this IP Address. I've already scheduled for one of these accounts to be deleted (Matthew Malan). Can you tell me the usernames of the active accounts? If I can prove I can login into these accounts, can you delete them?

Comment: @CodePlay You will need to contact the main Stack Exchange admins for this. I cannot give out private account details like that.

Comment: @JonW Would you please give me a link to contact them?

Answer (score 5):

As noted in the comments, this is part of the spam-prevention system: when activated, it limits the number of posts *from your network* to 1 per day.

If no one else on your network posts spam or abusive content, this restriction eventually expires. Conversely, if folks on your network *persist* in posting spam or abusive content, your network may be blocked from posting entirely.