# Should I try to give accepted answers for all my questions?

Tags: discussion, accepted-answer

I realize that your suppose to accept an answer if it worked for you. What if you have a *high up-voted* [question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/277327/why-can-i-not-post-my-one-post-per-day-on-ux), but the answer was found through the comments? Do I ask the user who made the comment to post it as an answer? **How important is it to accept answers for all your questions?** Is it worth begging users from the comments section to post the answer from the comments section to post their answer as a *official answer*?

### One possible problem

Some users feel answers in the *comment* section are easy answers and don't deserve to be answered. What do I do in this case. Delete the question?

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/77900/marking-comment-as-an-answer?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> What if you have a high up-voted question, but the answer was found through the comments? Do I ask the user who made the comment to post it as an answer?

Yes! If a comment is actually the answer to your question, ask the commenter to post his comment as an answer which works a lot of the times. If the commenter seems to be inactive or unresponsive for a really long time, post the comment as an answer yourself with attribution/credit to the commenter of course. That solves your other problem.

> How important is it to accept answers for all your questions?

Not important at all. If you have a million questions and there are no answers that truly answer your questions in your opinion, it is okay not to have a single accept. But if there is an answer that deserves the accept, give it the accept.

> Is it worth begging users from the comments section to post the answer from the comments section to post their answer as a official answer?

Don't beg. Just leave a comment like I said in the first paragraph.

Comment: Note that if you end up posting the comment as an answer for them, it might be a good idea to make it community wiki.