# You can only post 1 time each day due to the volume of spam and abuse originating from your network

Tags: discussion, flags, spam

I have been an active user lately on Stack Exchange Mathematics. If anyone can checkout my profile, I have posted my answers along with questions that I asked just to know if I attempted them correctly or not. I've never spammed nor abused anyone. Still I am getting this message.

> You can only post 1 time each day due to the volume of spam and abuse
>   originating from your network.

Is there anything that can be done about this? Can I get help from any moderator?

Comment: Yes, use a different network. Also see:  https://stackoverflow.com/help/abuse-block

Comment: Are you posting from a shared network? For example - a school/university/office?

Comment: Related: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/277327/why-can-i-not-post-my-one-post-per-day-on-ux.

Comment: Anyway, it's not really about you, it's because your IP address is used by others as well.

Comment: @rene I was using Ethernet cable port to access internet from my computer. I don't have wifi option in my computer.

Comment: @Oded I was using my Home internet

Comment: I didn't meant to switch between a cable and wifi, I meant switching to a different Internet Service Provider, or another Mobile operator (assuming your operator offers data). You could also use a vpn service.

Comment: To hopefully clarify, somebody else who is a customer of your ISP is probably posting gunk. Without information about your local upstream topology (which ISP, which netblock, etc) we can't really help. You probably don't want to post your IP address here if you can figure out a workaround (a VPN as suggested by @rene above should work fabulously).

Comment: By IP block, we talk what kind of range? A /24 ?

Answer (score 7):

You are probably accessing the internet via a shared IP address. Either from college/work or your ISP (Internet Service Provider) is assigning you a different one from their assigned block every time you connect.

Unfortunately there are spammers also using these IP addresses so you are automatically blocked along with them. There is nothing we can do about this.

If connecting from home you could try asking your ISP for a fixed IP address. This will become your IP address for all future connections. In the short term this might not help if we're already blocking that IP, but in the longer term, as you'll be the only person using it, the spam block will get removed - as long as *you're* not the spammer of course.

Answer (score 1):

Highly recommend the VPN option. There are plenty of free ones available.

The Tor Browser (for Firefox) might also be a solution, and is less of a hassle than installing a VPN.

**Update for mid-2018:** the Brave browser has a Tor client built right in. The browser is Chromium-based, and you can simply select "New private window with Tor"